Building webpart with custom property pane controls using @fluentui/react not working as expected (SPFx 1.19.0)
I was following the below tutorial to build custom property pane controls.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-web-part-property-pane/5-exercise-build-custom-controls
But after following the steps, when I try to add the webpart into workbench I am getting the below error in browser console (no error in gulp serve).

Could not load hello-world-web-part in require. Error: Script error
for "react"


Tried to search on the issue but unable to find the reason. Could some one please check this and guide me on what mistake am I doing here..
Repo: https://github.com/JefinDX/spfx_learn_01

The reason for the error was so trivial. I feel pity on myself.
SPFX v1.19.0 supports React v17.0.1 (And I was trying to use v17.0.2 through updating package.json. The project was created using No Framework option and lated I tried to add React into it.)

Related: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6923#issuecomment-823610274
But why could't spfx webpart just show much more meaning message rather that showing ERROR [object Object]
Found out that the reason for getting [object Object] error was due to an unwanted localizedResources mentioned in config.json. (@pnp/spfx-controls-react was not needed/installed. Don't remember how it got added here in the first place --- ohhh, I have only installed it just to check various things)
"localizedResources": {
    "HelloWorldWebPartStrings": "lib/webparts/helloWorld/loc/{locale}.js",
    "ControlStrings": "node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/loc/{locale}.js"
  }

Related GitHub issue (super super helpful): https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9675
